# Чем отличается эти «коды»?

Tags: swift, swift4

**Первое**

```
//Программа решающая квадратные неравенства
import Foundation
func solution(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double, sign: Int) -> (discriminant: Double, x1: Double, x2: Double?, cell: Int, answer: String) {
    var discriminant: Double = 0, x1: Double = 0, x2: Double = 0, cell: Int = 0, answer: String = ""
    discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c)//Нахождение дискриминанта
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)//Первый корень или единственный корень
    if discriminant > 0 {
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)//Второй корень
        a > 0 ? (cell = 1) : (cell = 4)
        if cell == 1 || cell == 4 {
            if (cell == 1 && sign == 1) || (cell == 4 && sign == 2) {
                answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x2)) \u{222a} (\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень) объединяя с (второй корень; +бесконечность)
            } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 2) || (cell == 4 && sign == 1) {
                answer = "(\(x2); \(x1))"//(первый корень; второй корень)
            } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 3) || (cell == 4 && sign == 4) {
                answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x2)] \u{222a} [\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень] объединяя с [второй корень; +бесконечность] включая первый и второй корень
            } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 4) || (cell == 4 && sign == 3) {
                answer = "[\(x2); \(x1)]"//[первый корень; второй корень] включая первый и второй корень
            }
        }
        return (discriminant, x1, x2, cell, answer)//Возвращает discriminant, x1, x2 типа Double, cell типа Int и answer типа String
    } else {
        if discriminant == 0 { discriminant == 0 && a > 0 ? (cell = 2) : (cell = 5) }
        else { discriminant < 0 && a > 0 ? (cell = 3) : (cell = 6) }
        if cell == 2 || cell == 5 || cell == 3 || cell == 6 {
            if (cell == 2 && sign == 1) || (cell == 5 && sign == 2) {
                answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x1)) \u{222a} (\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень) объединяя с (второй корень; +бесконечность)
            } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 2) || (cell == 5 && sign == 1) || (cell == 3 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) || (cell == 6 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) {
                answer = "Нет решения"//нет решения
            } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 3) || (cell == 5 && sign == 4) || (cell == 3 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) || (cell == 6 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) {
                answer = "(-\u{221e}; +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; +бесконечность)
            } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 4) || (cell == 5 && sign == 3) {
                answer = "\(x1)"//единственный корень
            }
        }
        return (discriminant, x1, nil, cell, answer)//Возвращает discriminant, x1 типа Double, x2 возвращается как nil, cell возвращается как Int и answer возвращается как String
    }
}
```

**Второе**

```
//Программа решающая квадратные неравенства
import Foundation

class SquaredUnequal {
    var a: Double = 0, b: Double = 0, c: Double = 0, sign: Int = 0, answer: String = ""
    init(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double, sign: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.sign = sign
    }
    func squaredSolution() {
        var discriminant: Double = 0, x1: Double = 0, x2: Double = 0, cell: Int = 0
        discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c)//Нахождение дискриминанта
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)//Первый корень или единственный корень
        if discriminant > 0 {
            x2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)//Второй корень
            a > 0 ? (cell = 1) : (cell = 4)
            if cell == 1 || cell == 4 {
                if (cell == 1 && sign == 1) || (cell == 4 && sign == 2) {
                    answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x2)) \u{222a} (\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень) объединяя с (второй корень; +бесконечность)
                } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 2) || (cell == 4 && sign == 1) {
                    answer = "(\(x2); \(x1))"//(первый корень; второй корень)
                } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 3) || (cell == 4 && sign == 4) {
                    answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x2)] \u{222a} [\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень] объединяя с [второй корень; +бесконечность] включая первый и второй корень
                } else if (cell == 1 && sign == 4) || (cell == 4 && sign == 3) {
                    answer = "[\(x2); \(x1)]"//[первый корень; второй корень] включая первый и второй корень
                }
            }
        } else {
            if discriminant == 0 { discriminant == 0 && a > 0 ? (cell = 2) : (cell = 5) }
            else { discriminant < 0 && a > 0 ? (cell = 3) : (cell = 6) }
            if cell == 2 || cell == 5 || cell == 3 || cell == 6 {
                if (cell == 2 && sign == 1) || (cell == 5 && sign == 2) {
                    answer = "(-\u{221e}; \(x1)) \u{222a} (\(x1); +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; первый корень) объединяя с (второй корень; +бесконечность)
                } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 2) || (cell == 5 && sign == 1) || (cell == 3 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) || (cell == 6 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) {
                    answer = "Нет решения"//нет решения
                } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 3) || (cell == 5 && sign == 4) || (cell == 3 && sign == 1 || sign == 3) || (cell == 6 && sign == 2 || sign == 4) {
                    answer = "(-\u{221e}; +\u{221e})"//(-бесконечность; +бесконечность)
                } else if (cell == 2 && sign == 4) || (cell == 5 && sign == 3) {
                    answer = "\(x1)"//единственный корень
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В чём преимущества первого кода над вторым (если таковы имеются) и наооборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу заметной разницы, разница только в том, что во втором случае непонятно зачем установка начальных аргументов переносится в инициализатор класса. Учитывая, что аргументы больше нигде не используются, это нарушает KISS принцип. Не надо так делать.

Так же, автору как минимум, надо вместо "\u{221e}" и т.п. символов использовать enum с константами.

Ну и лично я бы не стал использовать сокращенные операторы сравнения в не элементарных математических алгоритмах, т.к. ощутимо падает читаемость кода. Вообще впечатление что операторы сравнения в обоих примерах стоит перегруппировать, чтобы улучшить читаемость кода.

Пример enum:

```
enum Signs: String {
    case infinity = "\u{221e}"
    case join = "\u{222a}"
}
```

И использование:

```
answer = "(-\(Signs.infinity); \(x2)) \(Signs.join) (\(x1); +\(Signs.infinity))"
```

Добавление: Да, еще первый вариант кроме ответа возвращает дискриминант, а второй только ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за объективность, но хотелось бы видеть сам код в вашем исполнении, не полностью конечно же, я просто новичок в программировании, а что такое enum у меня представления нету, только видел что они есть и все, сокращённые операторы? Вы про Nil-Coalesing operator? И как их стоит перегруппировать?

Comment: Вот такую конструкцию: "discriminant == 0 && a > 0 ? (cell = 2) : (cell = 5)" стоит превратить в обычное сравнение, т.к. дальше еще куча сравнений, а разные стили мешают.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду обычное if ... {} else {}?

Comment: Да. Сокращенные операторы можно и нужно применять, но только если код в этом месте простой.

Comment: Добавил enum в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Добавление: Да, еще первый вариант кроме ответа возвращает дискриминант, а второй только ответ.